# Shell script cUrl command with URL being a variable

Tags: shell-script, curl

I am working on a shell script that would place get requests until the status is 202.

I have an issue with building the cURL command as mentioned below. Request is not being placed, even though the URL output by `echo` is correct. What am I doing wrong here?

```
get_path=$BASE_URL$location_header
echo "$get_path"
get_result="$(curl -i -s -X GET $get_path -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $4")"
```

Comment: Is `GET $getpath` supposed to be one single argument to the `-X` option? In any case, `$getpath` should be double-quoted.

Comment: I tried double-quoted, - didn't work

Comment: Could you show us the contents of `$get_path`, or at least let us know what type of error you get?  Also, when you double quoted, what did you double quote? The `$get_path` string or the `GET $get_path` string? Why do you even have `-X GET`? Isn't that the default?

Comment: get_path=`http://localhost:8010/api/v0/part-of-url/syncJobs/5lhf51rrd1jxw`

Comment: I see the following: `* Closing connection -1`

Comment: It has to do with that variable b/c when I substitute the variable with the URL, it works fine,

Comment: Possibly do parameter expansion (i.e., `${getpath}` ) to avoid issues with the shell?

Comment: Tried, doesn't do anything

Comment: This is how location_header is computed: location_header=$(echo "$post_result" | grep Location: |  awk '{print $2}')

Comment: @ThomasN `$get_path` and `${get_path}` is always 100% identical, there is absolutely no difference between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the `\r` invisible character, that I was adding to my URL `/syncJobs/{jobId}`. I was extracting `jobId` from the `Location` header of the POST operation.